# classpath and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I would like to export the `classpath` configuration of my `java` application from `eclipse`.

- how Can I set the `classpath` manually?
- how can I package it keeping the configuration the same.

The application is a `standard java application`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to get a single classpath string from your eclipse project that you can use to set the classpath on command line. But you can build your classpath using the information present in `.classpath` file. It basically will tell you all the required libs that are required in classpath. You may have to switch the view to navigator to see the .`classpath` file. You can do this by going to menu

> Window->Show View -> Navigator

You will see few entries in that file. You may find all the required jars under the kind "lib". Then you may use all those jars to build the classpath

Answer (score 0):

For a problem with dependencies with the classpath. I can set the project to use Maven.